# Spring Boot Admin on Kubernetes Certificate error

Tags: kubernetes, spring-boot-admin

Our Spring Boot admin deployed in Kubernetes was working fine and all of a sudden stopped working with the error below. We are trying to debug but couldn't find any information what it is trying to access to cause the certificate error. How is it accessing the namespace of the Kubernetes cluster it is deployed to get to the apps it needs to monitor? because that is maybe where the certificate error is originating from.

```
{"mdc":null,"exception":{"exception_class":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException","exception_message":"Operation: [list]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [null]  failed.","stacktrace":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [list]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [null]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:167)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:675)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.getServices(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:286)
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.getServices(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:282)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClient.getServices(CompositeDiscoveryClient.java:68)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.cloud.discovery.InstanceDiscoveryListener.discover(InstanceDiscoveryListener.java:126)
    at com.xxx.pn.services.config.TimedInstanceDiscoveryListener.periodicDiscovery(TimedInstanceDiscoveryListener.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.suppo
rt.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord
(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:133)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.intercept(OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealIntercep
torChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:472)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:435)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:418)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:160)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297
)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 64 more
"},"line_number":null,"class":null,"@version":1,"source_host":"pn-admin-dev-7d9646dfbd-4ddht","message":"Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task","thread_name":"scheduling-1","@timestamp":"2024-01-25T02:02:34.530+00:00","level":"ERROR","file":null,"method":null,"logger_name":"org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler","app_name":"pn-admin"}
{"mdc":null,"exception":{"exception_class":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException","exception_message":"Operation: [list]  for kind: [Endpoints]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [null]  failed.","stacktrace":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [list]  for kind: [Endpoints]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [null]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:167)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:675)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesCatalogWatch.catalogServicesWatch(KubernetesCatalogWatch.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concu
rrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.fin
dConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:133)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.intercept(OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.ja
va:472)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:435)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:418)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:160)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 60 more
"},"line_number":null,"class":null,"@version":1,"source_host":"pn-admin-dev-7d9646dfbd-4ddht","message":"Error watching Kubernetes Services","thread_name":"scheduling-1","@timestamp":"2024-01-25T02:02:34.610+00:00","level":"ERROR","file":null,"method":null,"logger_name":"org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesCatalogWatch","app_name":"pn-admin"}
{"mdc":null,"exception":{"exception_class":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException","exception_message":"Operation: [list]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [null]  failed.","stacktrace":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [list]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [null]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:167)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:675)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.getServices(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:286)
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.getServices(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:282)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClient.getServices(CompositeDiscoveryClient.java:68)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.cloud.discovery.InstanceDiscoveryListener.discover(InstanceDiscoveryListener.java:126)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.cloud.discovery.InstanceDiscoveryListener.onApplicationReady(InstanceDiscoveryListener.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:348)
    at org.spr
ingframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.ready(EventPublishingRunListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$ready$6(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:80)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.ready(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at com.xxx.pn.services.Application.main(Application.java:20)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/su
n.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterce
ptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:133)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.intercept(OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:472)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:435)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:418)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:160)
    ... 29 more
Cau
sed by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 74 more
"},"line_number":null,"class":null,"@version":1,"source_host":"pn-admin-dev-7d9646dfbd-4ddht","message":"Application run failed","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2024-01-25T02:02:34.718+00:00","level":"ERROR","file":null,"method":null,"logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","app_name":"pn-admin"}

Stack trace made readable by https://TidyTrace.com
```

We tried redeploying the admin app to Kubernetes and are expecting it to start without issues as we didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace you can see, that your Spring Boot Admin is using the fabric8 kubernetes client to get the instances from kubernetes:

```
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:84)
at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.getServices(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:286)
at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.getServices(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:282)
at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClient.getServices(CompositeDiscoveryClient.java:68)
at de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.cloud.discovery.InstanceDiscoveryListener.discover(InstanceDiscoveryListener.java:126)
```

The fabric8 client is then using the okhttp3 http client to talk to the k8s api via https. This is where the certificate error happens. So your java application does not accept the certificate of the k8s api server.